# Creating a list of fitness/nutrition/health bloggers to interview

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We recently did an interview of [Nutrition Diva](http://nutritiondiva.quickanddirtytips.com/) and wrote it up on our [blog](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/interview-with-nutrition-diva/). The interview was really well-received, and we even got her to come over and answer a question! I think it would be cool to interview some fitness and nutrition experts on a regular basis, so let's start a list of people we might want to contact!

1. [Get Fit Guy](http://getfitguy.quickanddirtytips.com/)
2. [JCD Fitness](http://jcdfitness.com/)
3. [Nerd Fitness](http://nerdfitness.com/blog)

Add some more!

Comment: Can we also put these bloggers on a blogroll on the Fitness.SE blog? I poked around earlier today, and I saw links in the admin. I guess the SE theme doesn't show them, or the widgets aren't set up?

Answer (score 2):

Some other suggestions:

- Zuzana, [BodyRock.tv](http://www.bodyrock.tv/)
- Darya Pino, [Summer Tomato](http://summertomato.com/)
- Michaele Kruger, [the better bites girl](http://thebetterbitesgirl.blogspot.com/)
- Mark Sisson, [Mark's Daily Apple](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/)
- [Yvonne Bishop-Weston](http://www.yvonne.bishop-weston.co.uk/)
- [Cassandra Forsythe](http://www.cassandraforsythe.com/)
- [DailyBurn Life](http://life.dailyburn.com/) bloggers (team list is on the side)
- [Lindsey Love Gallucci](http://race-orlando.com/)
- [GamerFitNation.com](http://gamerfitnation.com/)

Comment: We actually sponsored the [30 Day Primal Living Challenge](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/contest-what-does-living-primal-look-like/) on Mark's Daily Apple a few months ago, so that might be a good place to go next.

Comment: I've started a basic [Google Doc of interview questions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fm9UQPqX2WMkYCl0s7wovOPzSJJL_22kBZtdGXzXXqY/edit) we can ask Mark Sisson.

Comment: awesome! I'll look at it and try to add some stuff over the next few days.